# Create and overwrite channel permissions with Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to create a new channel and overwrite the permissions of `@everyone` so that only a selected role has access to the channel. No matter what I try it seems that the channel permissions remain unchanged. Last 2 attempts :

```
    Guild.createChannel(permName, 'text',[{
     type: 'role',
     id:359999680677019649,
     deny:0x400
    }])
    .then(channel => console.log(`Created new channel ${channel}`))
    .catch(console.error);

/////////

    Guild.createChannel(permName, 'text',[{
     type: 'role',
     id:359999680677019649,
     permissions:1024
    }])
    .then(channel => console.log(`Created new channel ${channel}`))
    .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Did you mean that you want the bot to create a channel, which only people with roles can see it? And those without roles cannot see the channel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ID field had to be a string.

```
    Guild.createChannel(permName, 'text',[{
     type: 'role',
     id:'359999680677019649',
     deny:0x400
    }])
    .then(channel => console.log(`Created new channel ${channel}`))
    .catch(console.error);
```